# RestKit Mixing Up Classes When Mapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, restkit

I am working on an application that creates table views from information provided by a web service.  I currently have two table views, one for "Regions" and another for "Categories," and am using RestKit to map the JSON information to the appropriate classes.  I have "Region" and "Category" classes to hold the data for each item.  Each table seems to work fine if it is the first table to be viewed.  However, if I view one table then switch to the other, the program encounters an exception.  It seems like it is getting my Category and Region classes mixed up if I view one table before viewing the other.

When I go to the view for Categories first, then go the the Regions view, I get this exception:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Category regionName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x938f1a0'"

When I go the the Regions View, then the Categories view, I see the following:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Region categoryName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xce87240'"

Here is the relevant code.  I realize it is a lot of code, but I don't know where my problem is:

If anyone has any ideas what is wrong, I'd appreciate the help.  Thank you!

Categories View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mCategoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    NSLog(@"Categories");

    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"My URL"];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

    RKObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class]];
    [categoryMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"categoryID", @"categoryID", @"parentID", @"parentID", @"categoryName", @"categoryName", @"childrenCount", @"childrenCount", @"parentCount", @"parentCount", @"catCount", @"catCount", nil];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:categoryMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    [self sendRequest];

}


- (void) sendRequest {
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mCategoryId forKey:@"CategoryId"] options:0 error:&error];


    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/Main/Process" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:jsonData MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

        NSDictionary *headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json", @"Content-Type", @"Basic ClientIdentifier%3Afc_ios_client%2CEndpoint%3A%2FCategories%2FGetChildCategoriesById", @"Authorization", nil];
        loader.additionalHTTPHeaders = headers;
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
            NSLog(@"Objects Loaded");
            categories = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        };
    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
        };
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", loader.URL.baseURL, loader.URL.relativePath]);
        loader = nil;
    }];
    objectManager = nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Category *category = [[Category alloc] init];
    category = nil;
    category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Category Cell");
    cell.textLabel.text = category.categoryName;
    NSLog(@"Cell returned");

    return cell;
}
```

Regions View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Region Listings Loading");

    mRegionId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"My URL"];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

    RKObjectMapping *regionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Region class]];
    [regionMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"regionHome", @"regionHome", @"regionID", @"regionID", @"regionName", @"regionName", @"parentCount", @"parentCount", @"parentID", @"parentID", @"childrenCount", @"childrenCount", @"parentName", @"parentName", nil];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:regionMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    NSLog(@"Mapping done");

    [self sendRequest];

}
- (void) sendRequest {

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:mRegionId forKey:@"RegionId"] options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"JSON Data");


    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/Main/Process" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:jsonData MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

        NSDictionary *headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json", @"Content-Type", @"Basic ClientIdentifier%3Afc_ios_client%2CEndpoint%3A%2FRegions%2FGetChildRegionsByIdWithBaseRegion", @"Authorization", nil];
        loader.additionalHTTPHeaders = headers;

        NSLog(@"Headers");

        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
            NSLog(@"Objects Loaded");
            regions = nil;
            regions = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        };
        loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
        };
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", loader.URL.baseURL, loader.URL.relativePath]);
    }];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Region *region = [[Region alloc] init];
    region = nil;
    region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"region");
    cell.textLabel.text = region.regionName;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where does the objectManager in the second viewcontroller come from?

Comment: The second view controller used basically the same code the create the objectManager.  I have added it into the Regions section to clarify that.